# What is the proper way to go about unit testing an application with most of the logic fed through one prerender method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, jsf, junit

I'm working on getting the unit test coverage from 0% to over 60% for an application that has almost 8,000 total instructions. Given the size of the app, I've been trying to make sure I set up test classes that are readable, make sense, and will be easy to add to in the future.

This JSF app loads a template using a prerender from the template in the hmtl. The template's prerender method simply calls the controller's prerender method which has all of the actual logic for loading the data to the page. This prerender method has the bulk of the controller's logic where data changes are made to the template.

I've been testing the controller logic through the template to make sure it's being properly connected and following how the application would actually be used. Is this the right mindset to take? Or am I getting unit tests mixed up with integration tests?

My prerender tests have gotten very long, with asserts on each of the properties being set on the template. Is there another way this should be done? How would I go about breaking this up into multiple tests?

Comment: *"Or am I getting unit tests mixed up with integration tests?"* I'd say yes. UnitTests test small portions of the code *in isolation*, that means that you have to *fake* incoming dependencies and *mock* outgoing dependencies (other parts of the code)  Each single test (-method) tests one (and only one) distinct expectation about what the unit does. A *unit* is any chunk of code that *changes for the same reason* (cite by Roy Osherove)

Comment: Thank you, @TimothyTruckle. So a unit test isn't testing everything about a method (such as the prerender) but rather it would test a specific behavior of the prerender?

Comment: *"So a unit test isn't testing everything about a method"* a single test method: no, all tests as a suit: yes - *"but rather it would test a specific behavior of the prerender?"* yes, and if the prerender is somehow structured then you would apply unit tests for each component of this structure...